# Designing a REST API with req/resp and pub/sub requirements

Tags: rest, publish-subscribe

Nowadays I'm designing a REST interface for a distributed system. It is a client/sever architecture but with two message exchange patterns:

- req/resp: the most RESTful approach, it would be a CRUD interface to access/create/modify/delete objects in the server.
- pub/subs: this is my main doubt. I need the server to send asynchronous notifications to the client as soon as possible.

Searching in the web I found that one solution could be to implement REST-servers in the server and client: [Publish/subscribe REST-HTTP Simple Protocol web services architecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22046328/publish-subscribe-rest-http-simple-protocol-web-services-architecture)

Another alternative would be to implement blocking-REST and so the client doesn't need to listen in a specific port: [Using blocking REST requests to implement publish/subscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780086/using-blocking-rest-requests-to-implement-publish-subscribe)

I would like to know which options would you consider to implement an interface like this one. Thanks!

Comment: Have considered using WebSockets ?

Comment: I read something about websockets but I am far to understand the coexistance between REST-HTTP and websockets

Comment: you may wanna look into this (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/331101/relationship-between-restful-uris-and-pubsub-topics)

Answer (score 7):

[Web Sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) can provide a channel for the service to update web clients live.  There's other techniques like [http long polling](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-12-01-http-long-polling/) where the client makes a "blocking" request (as you referred to it) where the service holds the request for a period of less than a timeout (say 50 sec) and writes a response when it has data.  The web client immediately issues another request.  This loop creates a continuous channel where messages can be "sent" from the server to the client but it's initiated from the client (firewalls, proxies, etc...)

There are libraries such as [socket.io](https://socket.io/), [signalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr) and many others that wrap this logic and even fallback from websockets to long polling gracefully for you and abstract away the details.

I would recommend write some sample web socket and [long polling examples](https://gist.github.com/bryanmacfarlane/7684730) just to understand but then rely on libraries like mentioned above to get it right.